# How to prevent screen readers from reading url after redirect?

Tags: navigation, screen-readers, wcag, wcag2.0

How can I prevent screen readers from reading the URL path? Currently, when I navigate from page 'A' to page 'B,' screen readers announce the new page as '/B,' which is the default behavior. I'd like to override this and make screen readers not announce anything after a redirect. Is this possible?

Comment: Then how does a screen reader know the new page loaded successfully?